# Aninhar um array plano em PHP para gerar um menu e submenus em HTML

Tags: php, html

Tenho um array mais ou menos assim:

```
Array
(
    [38] => Array
        (
            [name] => Categoria Raiz 1
            [link] => https://...
            [id_parent] => 0
        )

    [205] => Array
        (
            [name] => Subcategoria 1
            [link] => https://...
            [id_parent] => 38
        )

    [206] => Array
        (
            [name] => Subcategoria 2
            [link] => https://...
            [id_parent] => 38
        )
    [484] => Array
        (
            [name] => Categoria Raiz 2
            [link] => https://...
            [id_parent] => 0
        )
    [485] => Array
        (
            [name] => Subcategoria 3
            [link] => https://...
            [id_parent] => 484
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [name] => categoria Raiz 3
            [link] => https://...
            [id_parent] => 0
        )

    [147] => Array
        (
            [name] => Subcategoria 4
            [link] => https://...
            [id_parent] => 39
        )
)
```

Os índices são os IDs das categorias.

Eu preciso aninhar as categorias raiz com as suas subcategorias para criar um menu dropdown, mas estou errando na lógica. 
Estou utilizando a template engine `Smarty`, mas vou escrever o que eu já fiz em `PHP` puro para facilitar.

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $value) { ?>
    <li data-id_parent="<?php echo $value['id_parent']; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo $value['link']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></a>

    <?php
            if (!isset($id_anterior)) { ?>
                <ul>
    <?php   } else {
                if ($id_anterior != $value['id_parent']) { ?>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
    <?php       } 
            } 
    ?>
    </li>
    <?php

    $id_anterior = $key;
}
?>
```

Eu gostaria que a saída ficasse algo assim:

```
<li data-id_parent="0">
    <a href="https://...">Categoria Raiz 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li data-id_parent="38">
            <a href="https://...">Subcategoria 1</a>
        </li>
        <li data-id_parent="38">
            <a href="https://...">Subcategoria 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li data-id_parent="0">
    <a href="https://...">Categoria Raiz 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li data-id_parent="484">
            <a href="https://...">Subcategoria 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li data-id_parent="0">
    <a href="https://...">Categoria Raiz 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li data-id_parent="39">
            <a href="https://...">Subcategoria 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: como é a tabela?

Comment: @HananiaMizrahi A tabela é composta por colunas com os mesmos nomes das chaves do array, sendo a coluna `id` chave primária e a coluna `id_parent` chave estrangeira que referencia a própria tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua estrutura é recursiva, então por que não resolve usando recursividade? E você não precisa reestruturar seu *array*, basta filtrar os itens que deseja exibir a partir do valor de `id_parent`.

```
function menu($items, $parent = 0)
{
    $links = array_filter($items, function ($it) use ($parent) { 
        return $it['id_parent'] === $parent; 
    });

    if (count($links) === 0) {
        return '';
    }

    $menu = "<ul>";

    foreach ($links as $id => $link) {
        $menu .= "<li data-id_parent='{$parent}'>";
        $menu .= sprintf("<a href='%s'>%s</a>", $link['link'], $link['name']);
        $menu .= menu($items, $id);
        $menu .= "</li>";
    }

    $menu .= "</ul>";

    return $menu;
}
```

Assim ficando:

```
$items = [
    38 => [
            'name' => 'Categoria Raiz 1',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 0
    ],
    205 => [
            'name' => 'Subcategoria 1',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 38
    ],
    206 => [
            'name' => 'Subcategoria 2',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 38
    ],
    484 => [
            'name' => 'Categoria Raiz 2',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 0
    ],
    485 => [
            'name' => 'Subcategoria 3',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 484
    ],
    39 => [
            'name' => 'Categoria Raiz 3',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 0
    ],
    147 => [
            'name' => 'Subcategoria 4',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 39
    ]
];


echo menu($items);
```

Resultado (após formatado):

```
<ul>
  <li data-id_parent='0'>
    <a href='https://...'>Categoria Raiz 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li data-id_parent='38'><a href='https://...'>Subcategoria 1</a></li>
      <li data-id_parent='38'><a href='https://...'>Subcategoria 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-id_parent='0'>
    <a href='https://...'>Categoria Raiz 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li data-id_parent='484'><a href='https://...'>Subcategoria 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-id_parent='0'>
    <a href='https://...'>Categoria Raiz 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li data-id_parent='39'><a href='https://...'>Subcategoria 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro primeiro organizar o array...

```
$menu = [
    38 => [
            'name' => 'Categoria Raiz 1',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 0
    ],
    205 => [
            'name' => 'Subcategoria 1',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 38
    ],
    206 => [
            'name' => 'Subcategoria 2',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 38
    ],
    484 => [
            'name' => 'Categoria Raiz 2',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 0
    ],
    485 => [
            'name' => 'Subcategoria 3',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 484
    ],
    39 => [
            'name' => 'Categoria Raiz 3',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 0
    ],
    147 => [
            'name' => 'Subcategoria 4',
            'link' => 'https://...',
            'id_parent' => 39
    ]
];

function &find($needle, &$haystack) {
    $return = false;

    if (isset($haystack[$needle])) {
        $return = &$haystack[$needle];
    } else {
        foreach ($haystack as &$item) {
            if (isset($item['child'])) {
                $return = &find($needle, $item['child']);
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

function organize($menu) {
    $organized = [];

    foreach ($menu as $index => &$item) {
        $item['child'] = [];

        $ref = &find($item['id_parent'], $organized);

        if ($ref !== false) {
            $ref['child'][$index] = $item;
        } else {
            $organized[$index] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $organized;
}

$organized = organize($menu);
```

O resultado de `var_dump($organized);` será

```
array(3) {
  [38]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Categoria Raiz 1"
    ["link"]=>
    string(11) "https://..."
    ["id_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["child"]=>
    array(2) {
      [205]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Subcategoria 1"
        ["link"]=>
        string(11) "https://..."
        ["id_parent"]=>
        int(38)
      }
      [206]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Subcategoria 2"
        ["link"]=>
        string(11) "https://..."
        ["id_parent"]=>
        int(38)
      }
    }
  }
  [484]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Categoria Raiz 2"
    ["link"]=>
    string(11) "https://..."
    ["id_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["child"]=>
    array(1) {
      [485]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Subcategoria 3"
        ["link"]=>
        string(11) "https://..."
        ["id_parent"]=>
        int(484)
      }
    }
  }
  [39]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Categoria Raiz 3"
    ["link"]=>
    string(11) "https://..."
    ["id_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["child"]=>
    array(1) {
      [147]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Subcategoria 4"
        ["link"]=>
        string(11) "https://..."
        ["id_parent"]=>
        int(39)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

E então escreva a lista, por exemplo, com uma função recursiva:

```
function echoList($array) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($array as $item) {
        echo '<li data-id_parent="'.$item['id_parent'].'"><a href="'.$item['link'].'">'.$item['name'].'</a>';

        if (isset($item['child']) && !empty($item['child'])) {
            echoList($item['child']);
        }

        echo '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}

echoList($organized);
```

O HTML resultante:

```
<ul>
    <li data-id_parent="0">
        <a href="https://...">Categoria Raiz 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li data-id_parent="38"><a href="https://...">Subcategoria 1</a></li>
            <li data-id_parent="38"><a href="https://...">Subcategoria 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-id_parent="0">
        <a href="https://...">Categoria Raiz 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li data-id_parent="484"><a href="https://...">Subcategoria 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-id_parent="0">
        <a href="https://...">Categoria Raiz 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li data-id_parent="39"><a href="https://...">Subcategoria 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As funções são recursivas e permitem quantas listas, sublistas e sublistas dentro de sublistas forem necessárias